# Yacc conflict i cant fix

Tags: yacc

i've been trying to fix a shift/reduce conflict in my yacc specification and i can't seem to find where it is.

```
%union{
   char* valueBase;
   char* correspondencia;
}
%token pal palT palC
%type <valueBase> pal  
%type <correspondencia> palT palC Smth

%%

Dicionario  : Traducao
            | Dicionario Traducao
            ;

Traducao    : Palavra Correspondencia
            ;
Palavra : Base Delim
        | Exp
        ;

Delim : 
      | ':'
      ;

Correspondencia :
                | palC                  {printf("PT Tradução: %s\n",$1);}
                ;

Exp : Smth '-' Smth                  {aux = yylval.valueBase; printf("PT Tradução: %s %s %s\n", $1, aux, $3);}
    ;

Smth : palT                         {$$ = strdup($1);}
     |                              {$$ = "";}
     ;

Base    : pal                   {printf("EN Palavra base: %s\n",$1);}
        ;
```

Any help to find and fix this conflict would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Use the `-v` option to get a `y.output` file showing the parser states and the conflicts...

Comment: i've done that but i cant really understand the output of the file. Can you help?

Comment: You have problems when you have something (`Smth`) and nothing (the empty alternative for `Smth`).  It isn't clear what benefit `-` on its own (with two empty `Smth`'s on either side) provides.  Remove the empty alternative to `Smth`.

Comment: So i have 3 alternatives to catch. 
Number 1: smth '-'
Number 2: '-' smth
Number 3: smth '-' smth

Thats the reason behind that rule and the usage of the empty on smth

Answer (score 2):

So looking at the y.output file from your grammar, you have a shift/reduce conflict in state 13:

```
State 13

   10 Exp: Smth '-' . Smth

    palT  shift, and go to state 2

    palT      [reduce using rule 12 (Smth)]
    $default  reduce using rule 12 (Smth)

    Smth  go to state 16
```

Basically, what this is saying is that when parsing an `Exp` after having seen a `Smth '-'` and looking at a lookahead of `palT`, it doesn't know whether it should reduce an empty `Smth` to finish the `Exp` (leaving the `palT` as part of some later construct) OR shift the `palT` so it can then be reduced (recognized) as a `Smth` that completes this `Exp`.

The language you are recognizing is a sequence of one or more `Traducao`, each of which consists of a `Palavra` followed by an optional `palC` (`Correspondencia` that may be a `palC` or empty).  That means that you might have a `Palavra` directly following another `Palavra` (the `Correspondencia` for the first one is empty).  So the parser needs to find the boundary between one `Palavra` and the next just by looking at its current state and one token of lookahead, which is a problem.

In particular, when you have an input like `PalT '-' PalT '-' PalT`, that is two consecutive `Palavra`, but it is not clear whether the middle `PalT` belongs to the first one or the second.  It is ambiguous, because it could be parsed successfully either way.

If you want the parser to just accept as much as possible into the first `Palavra`, then you can just accept the default resolution (of shift).  If that is wrong and you would want the other interpretation, then you are going to need more lookahead to recognize this case, as it depends on whether or not there is a second `'-'` after the second `palT` or something else.